# Integrating DirectSmile with CS-Cart

Tags: integration, cs-cart

I'm trying to use cs-cart to sell e-cards. I want to use DirectSmile.com API to customize the card from cs-cart itself. I'm familiar with the DirectSmile API; that's not a problem. I'm just wondering if there is a way to change the cs-cart workflow a bit to allow users to customize and buy such products.

Is that possible with cs-cart?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You can create an add-on to work with the DirectSmile.com.
Look at the "Gift Certificates" add-on. This add-on allows to add to cart a new structured product: Gift card.

So you can do the same: Create your own type of products.